# Error on upload: "The difference between the request time and the server time is too large"

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-storage

I am getting this error when uploading files from my PC to Google Cloud:

> The difference between the request time and the Server time is too large.

I searched a lot but didn't find anything related to Google Cloud Storage. Could a proposed solution for Amazon S3 work for Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error often occurs when your computer clock is not synchronized properly. The reason for this problem is that [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1109?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1#04) and [Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference/v1/developer-guidev1#authentication) allows only a small time stamp variation of up to 15 minutes between the server and its requesting client (user pc). So the solution is same for both storage.

To get rid of this problem, you have to sync up your system clock. Also check to set the standard time and zone for your system.

Comment: ya, but same code is working on other pc with same time zone. 
 and having no issue. i have tried changing time zone on this pc, then it works fine. but i am not allowed to change the time zone of clients.

Comment: and time zone is also as according to their location.

Comment: it has nothing to do with the time zone, it's the clock time setting

Answer (score 3):

The other way you can avoid this error is to use OAuth2 instead of HMAC for authentication (OAuth2 does not require clock synchronization the way HMAC does). Please see https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth

Comment: But this is working fine with all other clients. 
i cant change the whole code,
please tell me some other way.